# Nginx not serving media files. Dockerizing django/nginx/gunicorn/postgresql

Tags: django, nginx

I have a project running in 3 docker containers. One is for django project itself, another one for postgres and the third one for nginx. My static files are served just fine while all media files are not found. However every file which was uploaded is properly saved in web container in media folder.

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn foodgram.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
      - ./media:/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/etc/nginx/html/static
      - ./media:/etc/nginx/html/media
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
```

Here is the nginx.conf:

```
events {}

http {

    include mime.types;

    server {


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }


        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            root /etc/nginx/html/;
        }

        location /media/ {
            autoindex on;
            root /etc/nginx/html/;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally nginx dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Error returned:

```
19#19: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/media/4.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

There are no nested folders in media/static folders.

Comment: Please, show example of URL for static and media file. And the structure of dirs/fils in static/media directories.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev updated

Comment: So it's telling you that there's no file called "4.jpg" in media directory. Do you see it on host OS? Do you see it from "web" container?

Comment: The original post tells that "However every file which was uploaded is properly saved in web container in media folder."

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev Yes, it is in the web container media folder and no it isn't saved on the local machine/remote server.

Comment: Can you add `:rw` for web container volumes and `:ro` for nginx? `./static:/static` in web -> `./static:/static:rw`; `./media:/media` in web -> `./media:/media:rw`; `./static:/etc/nginx/html/static` in nginx -> `./static:/etc/nginx/html/static:ro`; `./media:/etc/nginx/html/media` in nginx -> `./media:/etc/nginx/html/media:ro`

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev ain't helping mate

Comment: did you make `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build`?

Comment: and remove static named volume

Comment: if that will not help I suggest you to just add 2 named volumes - for statid and for media and use it in both nginx and web containers. like `- static:/static`

Comment: but mounting of host directory should work like a charm, just remove named volume and rebuild

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev What do you mean by 'remove named volume'?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev oh I got it now nvm

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev It did not help actually

Comment: Did you try named volume for both static/media in web/nginx container?